# How to update Widget with changed File variable using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have following widget in my app:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(

          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
               
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.photo_library,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              if (_imageFile != null) ...[
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
                    child: Image.file(_imageFile)),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   
                    FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                      onPressed: () =>
                          Get.toNamed(
                            AppRoutes.OCR_DETAILS,
                            arguments: {'image': _imageFile},
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]
            ],
          )
        );
      }
```

and following function to pick image:

```
Future _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
      _imageFile = selected;
      _imageLoaded=true;
  }
```

I would like to import file (_imageFile) and display it on current widget once is imported.
I would like to use GetX library.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Switched to choosing from gallery instead of camera. Also FYI the `pickImage` of that package is deprecated so we're using `getImage` instead.

Set up an ImageController GetX class.

```
class ImageController extends GetxController {
  File image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      image = File(pickedFile.path);
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

Initialize the controller, you can do it in your main or build method. Let's just do it in main here before you run your app.

```
Get.lazyPut<ImageController>(() => ImageController(), fenix: true);
```

Then on your page you can find the controller.

```
final controller = Get.find<ImageController>();
```

In the `onPressed` of your button fire the `getImage` method from your ImageController class

```
controller.getImage();
```

Then where ever you need it in your UI just throw this in there and you're good to go.

```
      GetBuilder<ImageController>(
                  builder: (_) {
                    return controller.image != null
                        ? Image.file(controller.image)
                        : Container();
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I think I'm pretty close to the solution, but somehow I dont see imported file in widget. Maybe you could take a look at the code:
https://github.com/ertiusmeo/flutter-getx-scaffolding-example-main

Comment: You didn't wrap the `Image.file(controller.image)` in a `GetBuilder< PickImageController>`, so there's nothing telling it to rebuild. That should do it for ya.